# Storing and displaying restaurant order details in Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a restaurant orders app using flutter where it displays the restaurant, the items one ordered from it, and the quantity of the items ordered.

As of now I'm trying to figure out the logic needed to accomplish this function using Dart first. So far this is the solution I came up with.  But I just wanted to know if there's a more efficient way of storing and displaying this type of data? Is there a solution that doesn't utilize too many lists and for loops? Still new to flutter and Dart hopefully I can get some insights.

```
void main() {
  int x =0;
  int range =0;

  List<String> restaurauntNames = ['Sbarro','Burger King','Mcdonalds'];
  List<int> orderNumber = [3,2,1];
  List<int> itemQuantity = [1,1,2,3,1,3];
  List<String> itemName= ['Spaghetti','Carbonarra','New York Pizza Large','French Fries','King Whopper','Big Mac'];
  
  for(String i in restaurauntNames) {
    print(i);
    for(int z=0; z!=orderNumber[x]; z++) {
      print(itemName[z+range] + ' - ' + itemQuantity[z+range].toString());
    }
    range = range + orderNumber[x];
    x++;
  }  
}
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information on your business case. For an example, how your orders are going to get linked with `itemQuantity` etc. As a small suggestion, try to use classes. E.g.: You can define a class to keep the information of each order. This class could contain a property `itemMap` where it contains the name of the ordered item as the key and the quantity as the value. Other properties might be `orderId`, `restaurantName`, etc.